# How do I refresh a ListFragment efficiently?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment with an ArrayAdapter to display a list of objects. I want to refresh the ListFragment's contents. The items themselves change their text a little and also change their order. I have over one hundred items and **the only way I've found to do this is clear the list and re-add them, but this feels ineffcient.**

*For example:*

ListFragment display unordered:

```
Object A
Object D
Object F
Object B
Object E
Object C
```

ListFragment display ordered:

```
Object A
Object B
Object C
Object D
Object E
Object F
```

I set up my ArrayAdapter like this:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Store>(mContext,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    OtherClass.list);
mAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

"OtherClass" is:

```
public class OtherClass extends Object {

    public ListArray<Object> list;
    ...
}
```

**The code in question:**

```
mAdapter.clear();
for (Object o : list) {
    mAdapter.add(store);
}
```

I've already read a lot of answers about how it works and how to use `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but none of them solve my problem or answer my question. **Is the only way to refresh the list done by adding/removing something from the list?**

Comment: I don't understand why notifyDataSetChanged does not work in this case.

Comment: Instead of using the code in question, why arent you making a new adapter with the "most recently sorted" list.

Comment: @CChi Sorry, I missed something. I should point out that the data being changed (i.e. those objects) are being changed in OtherClass's list. I am not directly manipulating via mAdapter.

Comment: @D.Tran Do you mean, instead of clearing and re-adding everything, I just make a new ArrayAdapter<Object>()?

Comment: OtherClass can see the mAdapter right? It seems like you need to just have OtherClass sort the list, then make a new adapter with that list and attach it.

Comment: Are you modifying the adapter and calling notifyDataSetChanged on the UI Thread? notifyDataSetChanged has to be called after the list is attached to the UI component. To answer you question, any modification to the List backing an array adapter requires a call to notifyDataSetChanged unless setNotifyOnChange is set to true.

Comment: Did i answer your question?

Comment: @D.Tran Not quite. What you've suggested works somewhat, but the problem is now the scroll position while I'm scrolling through the list resets every time the list is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you are attaching your adapter to, like say a listView, it can be unattached by setting it to null or to something else.

So instead of the code in question:

1). Sort the list.
2). Then call:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Store>(mContext,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    sortedList);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I hope this helps, as your question is still a little unclear. Generally if you have a list generated by an adapter, you dont want to be manually digging through the list as it is auto generated for you and doing so takes away from its ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. My solution is to stick to my original method which is: If you want to modify the list slightly, but have the list refresh so it's updated and also keep the scroll position then the only way to do this is to `clear()` and refill the list.

Source: http://vikinghammer.com/2011/06/17/android-listview-maintain-your-scroll-position-when-you-refresh/